# How do I use CocoonJS?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, game-engine

I made a game using Construct 2, I first try to use PhoneGap build to make the app but I realized at PhoneGap game are extremely slow. So I heard that CocoonJS can solve this problem. I tried to to make a CocoonJS game by exporting within Construct 2 but you are required to purchase the update. I also tried exporting to HTML Game and uploading to CocoonJS and testing on a iPhone where all I got was a black screen. I don't quite understand what format the game need to be in. What kind of struture is needed. If any has been in my situation or know how to solve it please help. I am no a really short deadline.

Comment: I also tried using appMobi I can't get that working either .

Answer (score 1):

For CocoonJS:

When exporting from Construct 2 with the CocoonJS option it packages it in a .zip file.  So try putting your files in a .zip and try that.  If you're getting a black screen after that you may not have packaged the .zip correctly, make sure the index.html isn't buried inside another folder in the .zip file.

For more information, check this out:  http://wiki.ludei.com/cocoonjs:launcherapp